# HTML Javascript <%= %> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, erb

While looking through a jquery plugin's source code on github, I stumbled upon a weird usage of  the `<%= %>` tag. I am aware that erb uttilizes those tags to execute ruby code within an HTML document, but I had never seen that used in javascript. As far as I can see, the tags are used in the same context as in erb, but instead execute Javascript code. How do those tags work and where can I find more information about them?

Example code:

```
</div>
 <div class="clndr-grid">
  <div class="days-of-the-week">
    <% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %>
      <div class="header-day"><%= day %></div>
    <% }); %>
    <div class="days">
      <% _.each(days, function(day) { %>
        <div class="<%= day.classes %>"><%= day.day %></div>
      <% }); %>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a variety of JS templating engines that do this.

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#template

Comment: [**EJS**](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) would be one of many commonly used templating system that uses that syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using `underscore.js`, especially the template function of the library:

More infomation here:

http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 1):

> When you build a JavaScript application, you'll almost certainly use
>   some JavaScript templates. Rather than use a library like jQuery (or
>   vanilla JavaScript) to update your HTML when values update, you can
>   use templates, which cleans up your code hugely.

There are many, some of them are

1. Underscore [Documentation](http://underscorejs.org/)
2. Mustache Templates  [Documentation on Github](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Refrence from creativebloq.com  To Read more [Click here](http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396)